# Formula correcta de hacer un filtro de preguntas en SOes

Tags: soporte, preguntas, filtros-de-calidad

Les comento mi duda. A mi no me gusta ver en SOes preguntas de etiquetas que yo no "manejo" me refiero a que si yo no uso `Java` no quiero ver preguntas de esa etiqueta. Así mismo no me gusta ver las preguntas "resucitadas" del bot. En su momento hice una petición para evitar eso pero igual no les gustó.

Entonces, para dicho propósito cree un filtro con la siguiente configuración:

[image: Filtro]

Pero la lista de preguntas que me muestra ese filtro no incluye varias preguntas nuevas que puedo ver en el index del sitio con etiquetas monitoreadas. Por ejemplo, ahora mismo el filtro me presenta estas preguntas:

[image: Preguntas Filtro]

Pero si yo me voy al index del sitio, veo lo siguiente:

[image: Preguntas Index]

En esa imagen, los check () representan preguntas nuevas y los Asteriscos (*) es una pregunta actualizada. Si se fijan en las etiquetas de cada pregunta, todas tienen un **ojo**, eso significa  que son etiquetas que yo las sigo o monitorizo.

Según creo, el filtro me debería mostrar esas preguntas porque yo tengo la opción de **Mis etiquetas Monitoreadas** seleccionada, pero no me las muestra. Es mas, si cambio a **Las Siguientes Etiquetas** en el filtro, lo primero es que me dice que solo puedo guardar 99 etiquetas monitoreadas y lo segundo es que aunque quite algunas etiquetas, sigue sin mostrar las preguntas de las etiquetas más vistas por mi, estas son **PHP**, **javascript**, **Wordpress** entre otras.

He probado de muchas maneras y no logro dar con la configuración ideal para que me muestre las preguntas de todas las etiquetas que sigo, que esconda las etiquetas que yo ignoro y que no me muestre las preguntas **resucitadas** por el bot :-S

Alguna idea??

Comment: ordena por actividad mas reciente.. si no, alguna ya hecha, que recibe respuestas posteriores no te va a aparecer...

Comment: Creo que la etiqueta que buscas es "soporte", cuya wiki dice "Solicitud de asistencia con alguna de las características del sitio."

Comment: @gbianchi, pero si pongo **Actividad más reciente** trae las resucitadas por el bot :-S (porque no entienden que nadie quiere responder preguntas del 2018 sin respuesta??) Pónganle un tiempo mínimo al bot, que se yo, 3 meses...

Comment: No es para que las contestes... es para simular movimiento.. y bue.. todo no se puede...

Comment: Si, entiendo que el sitio esta en decadencia y que quieren generar movimiento pero a los que le damos el verdadero movimiento eso nos molesta. En fin, como dice usted, no se puede todo. Buscare alguna alternativa para mi cometido.

Comment: Ese bot se puede desactivar???

Comment: @Yussef no, yo ya pedi eso y hasta eliminé la pregunta porque todos botarón en contra :-S

Comment: @OCHOA Yo te apoyo !!!

Comment: Pero no quieren, disque le quieren dar "movimiento" al sitio. Pero vamos que eso molesta a los que día a día estamos acá dandole el verdadero movimiento a SOes...

Comment: Podés tener preguntas de hace 20 años que igual son respondibles (¡acá no existe el concepto de _necrobump_!). Es cierto que puede molestar que el bot _resucite_ las preguntas, pero la cuestión es que [es.so] y sitios hermanos son como una base de conocimiento: puede que respuestas a preguntas de hace varios años sean útiles a otras personas en la actualidad. Por eso la cuestión de que la respuesta sea de ayuda no solo para OP (que incluso puede haber olvidado cómo lo resolvió) sino también para otros que _alguna vez_ lleguen a tener un problema similar.

Comment: @padaleiana, el problema no son las respuestas de preguntas del 2018. El problema son las **Preguntas sin Respuesta del 2018**, NADIE las responde, ni las responderá jamás (bueno solo he visto a uno revivir muertos y responder). Pero dígame, de que me sirve responder a una pregunta del 2018?? El OP no va a volver por su pregunta olvidada, los conceptos estarían super desfasados y no serviría de NADA responder a esas preguntas, DE NADA. Es más, cuando alguien usa `mysql_query` por ejemplo, lo primero que le decimos es que se pase a `mysqli` o `PDO`. Ese es el punto.

Comment: @OCHOA Es cierto lo que planteás, pero no se aplica a todos los lenguajes/bibliotecas/frameworks :)

Comment: Fácil, convénzame comenzando a responder todas las preguntas del 2015 en adelante. Porque sino lo hace, entonces solo son palabras vacías como dijo Bellatrix Lestrange. [Puede iniciar con estas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered), yo estaré pendiente de sus respuestas...

Comment: No necesito convencerte, es visible que esa es tu postura, y no es la única válida. Eso no quita que hay preguntas que sí valen la pena responder, no importa si se formularon ayer, hace una semana, o hace 5 años :) Y como ya mencioné, aquí no existe el concepto de _necrobump_, así que es totalmente válido responder a preguntas antiguas. Que algunos no le vean la utilidad, no significa que esté mal o sea innecesario.

Comment: Entonces su opinión es vacía, no lo veo respondiendo a ninguna de esas preguntas... Yo no digo que no es útil, lo que digo es que **NADIE LO HACE**, y si nadie responde eso, de que sirve? Yo comprendo que somos gatos y que no van a quitar el bot solo porque a mi no me guste, pero seamos serios, revivir preguntas es molesto e innecesario. Pero como ya dijeron, solo es por generar movimiento en el sitio, cosa que no sería necesaria si no siguieran dañando toda la plataforma SE como hasta hoy. PD: Este topic es sobre filtros no sobre el bot, esa pregunta ya me la rechazaron antes...

Comment: [Answers in old questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1806501/answers-in-old-questions)

Comment: @Marc pero esa query no se puede usar como filtro verdad? Yo también estaba pensando en usar el Query Composer pero al final aun estoy peleando con los filtros propios del sitio. Veré si me hago una query, aunque no se si me dejen meter los resultados en una ancla para que sean links...

Comment: @OCHOA La query no esta hecha para usarse para filtrar las preguntas, la he hecho para que se vean las preguntas antiguas que se responden actualmente

Comment: Aaaaa era para hacer ver que no tengo razón? Ok, pero ya vio la calidad de "Respuestas" a esas preguntas? Unas están respondidas sobre preguntas con respuestas aceptadas, otras son puro ChatGPT y otras las han editado. Y las que revisé no tenían la injerencia del bot, osea las respondieron porque la buscaron o por otra cosa, no porque el bot le haya puesto un comentario. Sigo preguntándome porque defienden algo que no sirve. Y sigo recordándoles que la pregunta es sobre filtros, su querido bot seguirá acá siempre :-)

Comment: A ver, un asunto es lo valido que es responder una pregunta antigua y otra es que el bot las resucite, son 2 cosas distintas. La página de inicio la usan los usuarios que moderan para ir revisando los últimos movimientos y el bot solo añade ruido.